# c++: Compilation of huge amount expressions failed with -O2 optimization?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I was using Eigen library to do some matrix calculation. I have to define a large matrix(actually not that large, just 300x300) with each element composed of long complex exponential expressions.

To give an impression of what I mean, I copied a small part of my matrix definition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{
typedef std::complex<double> cd;
MatrixXcd h(300,300);
double kx,ky;
kx=1.;
ky=1.;
h.setZero(300,300);
h(0,0)=cd(6.942755,0.) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 2.0238820899708214*kx - 7.55323078829979*ky)) - 0.010802/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 5.529348698328969*kx - 5.529348698328969*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 7.55323078829979*kx + 2.0238820899708214*ky)) - 0.010802/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 5.529348698328969*kx + 5.529348698328969*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 2.0238820899708214*kx + 7.55323078829979*ky));
h(0,2)=cd(0.,0.) + 0.095916/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky)) - 0.131689/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 7.55323078829979*kx + 2.0238820899708214*ky));
h(0,3)=cd(-0.10825,0.) - 0.011519/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky));
...
...//6000 more lines omitted here
}
```

I am using mingw-w64 on windows, the compiler was set up fine. But when I compile the above code with

```
g++ -O2 code.cpp
```

the compilation fails with popup dialog!

[image]

and if I look at the task manager carefully, the compilation stop at memory usage about 1GB.

However, if I compile the code with `-O0` option again, that is to disable all optimization, the compilation succeeded, even though the memory usage reached a peak close to 2GB. **So the failure definite not due to memory**.

What is more, **I can confirm this behavior is nothing to do with `Eigen` library.** Even if I don't use `Eigen` and replace all assignment to the same variable, like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
typedef std::complex<double> cd;
cd tmp;
double kx,ky;
kx=1.;
ky=1.;
tmp=cd(6.942755,0.) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 2.0238820899708214*kx - 7.55323078829979*ky)) - 0.010802/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 5.529348698328969*kx - 5.529348698328969*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 7.55323078829979*kx + 2.0238820899708214*ky)) - 0.010802/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 5.529348698328969*kx + 5.529348698328969*ky)) + 0.043986/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 2.0238820899708214*kx + 7.55323078829979*ky));
tmp=cd(0.,0.) + 0.095916/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky)) - 0.131689/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. + 7.55323078829979*kx + 2.0238820899708214*ky));
tmp=cd(-0.10825,0.) - 0.011519/exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky));
... //6000 more lines omitted
}
```

The compilation also fails for `-O2` option.

Also, **the problem is not limited to mingw compiler**. I also tried intel parallel studio icl.exe. The situation is even worse, the compilation takes more than 30 minutes and seems that it will go on and on, and I have no patience to wait it finished, and probably it may also failed at the end.

**So my question is what cause the failure of compilation with `-O2`? How to make `-O2` work for my code (which has huge amount of expressions)? And also what surprise me is that though there are many expressions, they are simply composed of elementary `exp` function, why the compilation takes so much time and memory? Any trick to make the compilation faster?**

**update**

According to  Marc Glisse's suggestion, I run the following. `-O1` works, but what I want is at least O2, because the code is for scientific computing purpose. Speed is important.

```
R:\>g++ -O1  -ftime-report  eigen.cpp

Execution times (seconds)
 phase setup             :   0.01 ( 0%) usr    1540 kB ( 0%) ggc
 phase parsing           :   6.06 ( 5%) usr  412774 kB (25%) ggc
 phase lang. deferred    :   0.18 ( 0%) usr    6491 kB ( 0%) ggc
 phase opt and generate  : 122.65 (95%) usr 1203926 kB (74%) ggc
 |name lookup            :   0.61 ( 0%) usr   39968 kB ( 2%) ggc
 |overload resolution    :   2.18 ( 2%) usr  151685 kB ( 9%) ggc
 garbage collection      :   1.48 ( 1%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 callgraph construction  :   0.65 ( 1%) usr   28545 kB ( 2%) ggc
 callgraph optimization  :   0.41 ( 0%) usr       6 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa dead code removal   :   0.02 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa inlining heuristics :   0.58 ( 0%) usr    6172 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa reference           :   0.02 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa profile             :   0.11 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 ipa pure const          :   0.20 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 cfg cleanup             :   0.04 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 trivially dead code     :   0.05 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df scan insns           :   0.09 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df multiple defs        :   0.03 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live regs            :   0.13 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live&initialized regs:   0.04 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df reg dead/unused notes:   0.17 ( 0%) usr    2440 kB ( 0%) ggc
 register information    :   0.01 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 alias analysis          :   0.05 ( 0%) usr    1546 kB ( 0%) ggc
 alias stmt walking      :  27.43 (21%) usr   19006 kB ( 1%) ggc
 rebuild jump labels     :   0.03 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing           :   0.63 ( 0%) usr    8732 kB ( 1%) ggc
 parser (global)         :   0.30 ( 0%) usr   80513 kB ( 5%) ggc
 parser struct body      :   0.36 ( 0%) usr   20184 kB ( 1%) ggc
 parser enumerator list  :   0.03 ( 0%) usr    1004 kB ( 0%) ggc
 parser function body    :   3.52 ( 3%) usr  253532 kB (16%) ggc
 parser inl. func. body  :   0.16 ( 0%) usr    6243 kB ( 0%) ggc
 parser inl. meth. body  :   0.24 ( 0%) usr   12261 kB ( 1%) ggc
 template instantiation  :   0.75 ( 1%) usr   36791 kB ( 2%) ggc
 early inlining heuristics:   0.74 ( 1%) usr   78738 kB ( 5%) ggc
 inline parameters       :   0.60 ( 0%) usr    3273 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integration             :  34.96 (27%) usr  421223 kB (26%) ggc
 tree gimplify           :   0.93 ( 1%) usr   78917 kB ( 5%) ggc
 tree eh                 :   1.81 ( 1%) usr  147729 kB ( 9%) ggc
 tree CFG construction   :   0.26 ( 0%) usr   47487 kB ( 3%) ggc
 tree CFG cleanup        :   0.92 ( 1%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree copy propagation   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PTA                :   1.80 ( 1%) usr     167 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PHI insertion      :   0.07 ( 0%) usr     519 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA rewrite        :   1.63 ( 1%) usr   97983 kB ( 6%) ggc
 tree SSA other          :   0.13 ( 0%) usr      17 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA incremental    :  28.75 (22%) usr       5 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree operand scan       :   2.13 ( 2%) usr   65917 kB ( 4%) ggc
 dominator optimization  :   0.08 ( 0%) usr    2043 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SRA                :   2.65 ( 2%) usr   56210 kB ( 3%) ggc
 tree CCP                :   2.42 ( 2%) usr   37765 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree split crit edges   :   0.11 ( 0%) usr    2953 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree reassociation      :   0.04 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree FRE                :   3.35 ( 3%) usr   35524 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree code sinking       :   0.01 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree linearize phis     :   0.01 ( 0%) usr       6 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree backward propagate :   0.02 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree forward propagate  :   0.38 ( 0%) usr       8 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree conservative DCE   :   0.13 ( 0%) usr       1 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree aggressive DCE     :   0.33 ( 0%) usr       2 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree DSE                :   0.45 ( 0%) usr       4 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA uncprop        :   0.01 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dominance frontiers     :   0.06 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dominance computation   :   0.65 ( 1%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 out of ssa              :   0.09 ( 0%) usr       1 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand vars             :   0.02 ( 0%) usr     765 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand                  :   0.13 ( 0%) usr   13796 kB ( 1%) ggc
 post expand cleanups    :   0.03 ( 0%) usr    2868 kB ( 0%) ggc
 forward prop            :   0.08 ( 0%) usr     156 kB ( 0%) ggc
 CSE                     :   0.08 ( 0%) usr     304 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead code elimination   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead store elim1        :   0.09 ( 0%) usr     763 kB ( 0%) ggc
 dead store elim2        :   0.08 ( 0%) usr     613 kB ( 0%) ggc
 loop init               :   0.15 ( 0%) usr      65 kB ( 0%) ggc
 branch prediction       :   0.12 ( 0%) usr      19 kB ( 0%) ggc
 combiner                :   0.10 ( 0%) usr     216 kB ( 0%) ggc
 if-conversion           :   0.01 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integrated RA           :   0.43 ( 0%) usr    9659 kB ( 1%) ggc
 LRA non-specific        :   0.26 ( 0%) usr     305 kB ( 0%) ggc
 LRA virtuals elimination:   0.03 ( 0%) usr     304 kB ( 0%) ggc
 LRA create live ranges  :   0.03 ( 0%) usr     152 kB ( 0%) ggc
 LRA hard reg assignment :   0.02 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 reload CSE regs         :   0.19 ( 0%) usr     916 kB ( 0%) ggc
 thread pro- & epilogue  :   0.04 ( 0%) usr      14 kB ( 0%) ggc
 hard reg cprop          :   0.07 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 shorten branches        :   0.08 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 final                   :   0.16 ( 0%) usr     279 kB ( 0%) ggc
 initialize rtl          :   0.01 ( 0%) usr      12 kB ( 0%) ggc
 rest of compilation     :   0.31 ( 0%) usr     879 kB ( 0%) ggc
 remove unused locals    :   2.24 ( 2%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 address taken           :   1.00 ( 1%) usr   37564 kB ( 2%) ggc
 rebuild frequencies     :   0.02 ( 0%) usr       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 : 128.90           1624743 kB
```

Comment: You could try compiling an example of intermediate size with -ftime-report to see what takes time. But note that it is often recommended to stick to -O1 for large auto-generated source files (you don't mention if you tried -O1).

Comment: Hi, @MarcGlisse Thank you for your suggestion. I updated my post. `-O1` works, but I want `-O2`

Answer (score 0):

I see some redundancy in expression like the term :

`exp(cd(0,1)*(0. - 7.55323078829979*kx - 2.0238820899708214*ky))` seen in h(0,2) and h(0,3).

The `-O2` forces the compile to detect and reuse patterns. It seems the complexity is too high with 6k lines of expressions. You could help gcc with tmp variables. This is equivalent of building a dependancy graph and then generate the code.

Comment: Hi, norisknofun. Thank you for answering. repeated pattern can account for long compilation time, but I think the compilation should not be failed. What cause the  failure?